# Deserialize a nested DataSet from Json String with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I try to deserialize a DataSet from a JSON String with Json.NET. The Json String contents a status, message and the table that I want to use:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "",
    "table": [{
        "column1": "value1",
        "column2": "value2"
    }, {
        "column1": "value3",
        "column2": "value4"
    }]
}
```

Here my source:

```
    public class RequestResult
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    ...

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var rr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestResult>(sr);

    // Without status and message the following works fine like here: 
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm
    DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(sr);
    gridControlMain.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["table"];
```

If I use the Json String without status and message it works fine, but I need status and message! Exception message from Json.NET is: 
*Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got String. Path 'status', line 1, position 14*. 
How can I manage that?

Best regards

Comment: You are missing quotation marks around status and message variables

Comment: I've edited my post but that solves not the problem!

Comment: share your source code which you have currently used

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested DataSet. In .NET DataSets contain DataTables with relations. What did you try to do? Please post your code.

Comment: I've edited my post above!

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show a DataTable, it's an object with `status`, `message` and `table` properties

Comment: yes that is because the "table" is json array which we can directly convert to Dataset and if status and message are added then it will add json object with "table" array so it is not converting
what are you trying to show in grid
gridControlMain

Comment: If eventually you are going to use datatable as the datasource of DataGrid then why do you need to deserialize string to DataSet. You can add a new property of type DataTable in RequestResult and deserialize the string to RequestResult.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya nobody mentioned a grid until now, besides you *don't* need a DataSet or DataTable for binding. All .NET platforms support binding to objects and strongly-typed collections. This isn't related to the question anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did you miss the line `gridControlMain.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["table"];` ? As per this line Datatable is being used as data source.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that is *not* the question. The question is about Json deserialization. You don't need a DataSet or DataTable for data binding anyway. Asking the OP `Why don't you deserialize to RequestResult? You already have the proper class` is a valid question. A very valid question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not sure what point you are trying to make. My suggestion was around avoid unnecessary deserialization and serializing to the class which is actually being used at the end. I also recommended a similar solution as the answer you provided below by saying `You can add a new property of type DataTable in RequestResult and deserialize the string to RequestResult.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet shows an *object* with three properties, `status`, `message` and `table`. This object can't be deserialized as a DataTable. The `table` property can.

You can deserialize this snippet to a class with two string and one DataTable property, eg:

```
class MyTableUtilClass
{
    public string Status{get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public DataTable Table{get;set;}
}


var myUtil=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTableUtilClass>(jsonText);
DataTable myTable=myUtil.Table;
```

Comment: You made my day :-)