# Issue converting JSON string to DataTable C#

Tags: c#, json

Having an issue getting a JSON string to convert into a C# Datatable...

Here is an example of the JSON string that gets returned to me code from an API

```
   {
  "Code": 0,
  "Result": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Reference": "101",
      "Asset": 200,
      "Event": 1,
      "DateEventStart": "2/10/2017 9:08:33 PM",
      "DateEvent": "2/11/2017 1:00:14 AM"
    }
]
}
```

So that comes in from the API and I read it, then attempt to create a DataTable like this

```
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding);
        responsetext = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(responsetext);
```

However this gives the following error:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got
>   StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1

I'm new to dealing with JSON in C# so any help appreciated. I think that my string is invalid in some way in terms of getting it to be parsed, but I don't know. If there is more info required let me know

EDIT:
Ok I followed the link that Xingxing Qiao put - makes sense. I now get a different error which I think is due to what I've put into the class that the JSON gets deserialised into -

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApplication7.TrackingResponse]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'Code', line 1, position 8.

Here is that class...is it because I don't include 'Code' and 'Result' from the JSON (see string above)

```
public class TrackingResponse
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string DateEventStart { get; set; }
    public string DateEvent { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: check this, [convert-json-to-datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Deserialize a nested DataSet from Json String with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090584/3744182).  As in that answer, you need a wrapper root object to contain your `DataTable`.  Does that answer your question sufficiently, or do you need the specific root object?

Comment: Thanks @XingxingQiao, see my further comments above

Comment: Why do you need a DataTable in the first place? Plain model objects are far easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your root JSON container is not an array, it is an object.  As explained in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/):

- An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
- An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

Newtonsoft tries to map a `DataTable` (as well as objects of type [IEnumerable, List, and Array](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists)) from and to an array, and as the root container is not an array, it fails with the *Expected StartArray, got StartObject* error.

Since your root container is an object with two properties `"Code"` and `"Result"`, you need to create a POCO to which to bind those properties.  Now, the value of `"Result"` *is* an array, so could be mapped to a `DataTable`, or to a `List<T>` for some appropriate `T`.  To generate the necessary classes, you can use a code-generation tool such as http://json2csharp.com/ or [Paste JSON As Classes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/) in visual studio and get something like the following (slightly modified to make the root object generic):

```
public class Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public int Asset { get; set; }
    public int Event { get; set; }
    public string DateEventStart { get; set; }
    public string DateEvent { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject<T>
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

You can now deserialize your JSON as a `RootObject<DataTable>` or a `RootObject<List<Result>>`:

```
var rootOfList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject<List<Result>>>(responsetext);
```

Or

```
var rootOfTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject<DataTable>>(responsetext);
DataTable table = rootOfTable.Result;
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5rdbrS).

Comment: That has helped me immensely - much appreciated (and thanks for explaining it rather than just sticking some code on here)